# Drive in fstab via fuse.sshfs are not mounted after reboot

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs, fuse

Using Ubuntu 22.04. My fstab entry:

```
some_user@some_storagebox.com:~/somedir /mnt/volume fuse.sshfs defaults,allow_other,reconnect,_netdev,users,ServerAliveInterval=15,identityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=101,gid=101,ServerAliveCountMax=3 0 0
```

The first interesting thing is that I'm trying to test if fstab line works by trying to mount volume with:

```
mount /mnt/volume-1
```

storage requires to enter password although I'm using rsa key with

> identityfile

parameter.

After reboot volume wasn't be mounted.
I have no clue why it happening.

Comment: `fstab` is not a shell, `~` is not going to be expanded, use full path names in `fstab`.

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted identityfile path with a full dir, but still stuck in the same.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1477827/edit) your question accordingly with your recent fstabline.

Comment: There is still a `~` in your fstab line `~/somedir` is not going to work.

Comment: Yeah, because with a full path directory is not found at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to mount an sshfs volume using fstab and you are being prompted for a password even though you are using an rsa key with the `identityfile` parameter.

One possible solution is to use the `sshpass` command in your fstab entry. The parameter would look like such, and simply executes `sshpass -f /root/sftp.pass ssh` when connecting:

```bash
ssh_command=sshpass\\040-f\\040/root/sftp.pass\\040ssh
```

For example, to connect as username with password secret to a server sftp.example.com on port 2222 your fstab entry could look something like this:

```bash
username@server:/remote/directory /local/mountpoint fuse.sshfs defaults,_netdev,user,idmap=user,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,reconnect,ssh_command=sshpass\\040-f\\040/root/sftp.pass\\040ssh,port=2222 0 0
```

You can also check out this [Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473648/auto-mount-sshfs-volume-through-fstab-with-password-auth) which explains how to auto mount sshfs volume through fstab with password auth.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather connect only with a `identityfile` instead of a password. Just trying to identify why password is still required when I provide `identityfile` on fstab.